# How to add a class property to a list of instances

Tags: c#

I'm newbie in `C#`. Perhaps this is too simply to resolve but I'm really away of the solution.

I have this class:

```
public class TestSetups : TabelaCtset
{
    public IList<TabelaCtsca> ValSetup { get { return m_valsetup; } }
    private static List<TabelaCtsca> m_valsetup;

    /// Constructor
    public TestSetups(IDefinitionList dlist)
        : base(dlist)
    {
        m_valsetup = new List<TabelaCtsca>();
    }
}
```

I have another `class` called `TestCase`

```
public class TestCase : TabelaCttes
{
    public IList<TestSetups> Setups { get { return m_setups; } }
    private List<TestSetups> m_setups;
...
    testcase.m_setups = new List<TestSetups>();

    defs = gdl.GetDefinitions(testcase);
    while (defs.MoveNext())
        {
            TestSetups testsetup = new TestSetups(defs);
            IDefinitionList valsetup = gdl.GetDefinitions(testsetup);
            {
                TabelaCtsca ctsca = new TabelaCtsca(valsetup);
                testsetup.ValSetup.Add(ctsca);
            }
            testcase.Setups.Add(testsetup);    
        }
        return testcase;
...
}
```

I want to put all `ctsca` values in a `ValSetup` list. All works fine, except this line `testcase.Setups.Add(testsetup);`: I have the the properties of `TestSetups` class but my `ValSetup` property is always empty, when my while goes to another iteration.

Sorry for this weird explanation. I'm able to explain in more detail.

**Update:** In this situation, I store in each TestSetup just the last ValSetup value and not all the ValSetup of each TestSetup.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the function? And where it's called from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made `m_valsetup` a static property, but you're re-initializing every time you create a new instance of `TestSetups`. If you want it to be a shared list across all instances of `TestSetups`, then you could use a property initializer like this:

```
private static List<TabelaCtsca> m_valsetup = new List<TabelaCtsca>();
```

And remove the initialization of it in the constructor.

If you didn't intend for the list to be shared, then just remove the `static` keyword from its definition.

Comment: I want a TestCase with a list of TestSetups who have a list of ValSetups. With your solution I have all the ValSetups in all TestSetups.

Comment: I made it! Thanks a lot.